# How to get Calling Gridview name in ObjectDataSource Selecting event

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, objectdatasource

I have 2 gridviews, `gv1` and `gv2` and an `ObjectDataSource` with the id `ods1`. Both the gridviews are pointing to `DataSourceID="ods1"`.

My question is, how do I know in selecting event of an `ObjectDataSource` that which gridview has called `ods1`. I want to set input parameters based on which gridview has made a call to the `ods1`.

Comment: Can you post your code.? that what you have tried..?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not easily possible and it feels like it would be against the idea behind ODS.

You can delegate two `ObjectDataSource`s to get the data from THE SAME repository class but still, you need two different data sources if you want to have two different sets of parameters. Thus, you do not duplicate code as the repository code is shared between object data source instances.

Answer (score 0):

## Warning: Hack ahead

I tend to agree with [Wiktor Zychla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498880/how-to-get-calling-gridview-name-in-objectdatasource-selecting-event/15500362#15500362), but if you *really* need to do this...

The only thing I can think of to accomplish this would be to handle the "DataBinding" event of each of your `GridView`s, and set a session variable to indicate which one is about to call the `ObjectDataSource` "Selecting" event.

So you would have your `GridView` methods:

```
protected void gv1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["currentGridID"] = "gv1";
}
```

and

```
protected void gv2_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["currentGridID"] = "gv2";
}
```

And then, your `ObjectDataSource` could check that Session variable, to see which ID is in it while the `ObjectDataSource` is firing this time:

```
protected void ods1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["currentGridID"] == "gv1")
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the name of the gridview which call the objectdatasource

You can do something like:

```
string CallingGridName = ((ObjectDataSourceID)sender).ID;
```

Comment: This is not correct.  First off, you cannot cast the `sender` variable to something that's not a real type, you'd need to cast it to `ObjectDataSource`.  Secondly, even if you did that, your code is still getting the ID of the `ObjectDataSource`, and the OP is asking for the ID of the `GridView`.

Comment: (in your defense, this is how I read the question the first time as well, so it's an easy mistake to make)